# Combine and sort new entry with any older matching values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How can I use a single **Formula** as in the table below (cell D2) that will concatenate a new dated entry with any prior matching values in a single cell that is sorted in asending date order?

| Color | Date | Description | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | **`Formula`** |
| Blue | 6/3/2021 | paper | 06/03/2021: paper |
| Green | 6/3/2021 | grassy knoll | 06/03/2021: grassy knoll |
| **Blue** | 6/8/2021 | sky | 06/03/2021: paper 06/08/2021: sky |
| Green | 6/8/2021 | car | 06/03/2021: grassy knoll 06/08/2021: car |
| Green | 6/9/2021 | Salad | 06/03/2021: grassy knoll 06/08/2021: car 06/09/2021: Salad |

In the above table the formula, for example, matches "Blue" in A5 to the same value in A3, then concatenates `B5&": "&C5`with the prior value that was outputed in D3. It does the same in D5:D7. However, in D3:D4 since there is no prior entry it simply returns the values in B3:C3 in D3 and B4:C4 in D4.

I can currently acheive something similar to this as shown in the table below which I also added labels in the first column to display the line # and showed other `formulatext()` in the second displayed line (which was actually line 3 in the spreadsheet), though it takes several steps and dragging down a few formulas including formula 1.

Formula 1

```
`=IFERROR(Index(FILTER(D$2:D2,$A$2:$A2=$A4),match(min(abs(FILTER($B$2:$B2,$A$2:$A2=$A4)-$B4)), abs(FILTER($B$2:$B2,$A$2:$A2=$A4)-$B4), 0)))`
```

| Color (cell A1) | Date (B) | Description (C) | Date & Description (D) | Formula (E) | Output (F) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 Formulas |  |  | =text(B4,""mm/dd/yyyy"")&"": ""&C4 | SEE FORMULA 1 | =IF(E4<>D4,E4&CHAR(10)&D4,D4) |
| 4 Blue | 6/3/2021 | paper | 06/03/2021: paper |  | 06/03/2021: paper |
| 5 Green | 6/3/2021 | grassy knoll | 06/03/2021: grassy knoll |  | 06/03/2021: grassy knoll |
| 6 Blue | 6/8/2021 | sky | 06/08/2021: sky | 06/03/2021: paper | 06/03/2021: paper 06/08/2021: sky |
| 7 Green | 6/8/2021 | car | 06/08/2021: car | 06/03/2021: grassy knoll | 06/03/2021:grassyknoll 06/08/2021: car |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,lambda(color,date,desc,if(color="",,join(char(10),
     byrow(sort(filter({B2:date,C2:desc},A2:color=color),1,1),lambda(Σ,join(": ",text(index(Σ,,1),"mm/dd/yyyy"),index(Σ,,2))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Very impressed! Thank you.

Comment: IF C2:C were a value that was concatenated such that the value in C2 were arrayformula(F2:F&G2:G) how could I adapt the formula so that that I could reference F&G directly?

Comment: For example: =map(A2:A,B2:B,[REPLACE],lambda(color,date,desc,if(color="",,join(char(10),
     byrow(sort(filter({B2:date,[REPLACE]:desc},A2:color=color),1,1),lambda(Σ,join(": ",text(index(Σ,,1),"mm/dd/yyyy"),index(Σ,,2))))))))

Comment: Try: `=map(A2:A,B2:B,F2:F,G2:G,lambda(color,date,Σ,Δ,if(color="",,join(char(10),byrow(sort(filter({B2:date,F2:Σ&G2:Δ},A2:color=color),1,1),lambda(Σ,join(": ",text(index(Σ,,1),"mm/dd/yyyy"),index(Σ,,2))))))))`

Comment: If E2:E was a value that was populated by a Vlookup such that the value in E2 was =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, {Sheet2!A2:A&Sheet2!B2:B, Sheet2!E2:E}, 2, FALSE))) how would I adapt the following formula so that it could include the Vlookup directly? map(A2:A,B2:B,D2:D,[REPLACE],lambda(color,date,Σ,Δ,if(color="",,join(char(10),byrow(sort(filter({B2:date,[REPLACE]:Σ&E2:Δ},A2:color=color),1,1),lambda(Σ,join(": ",text(index(Σ,,1),"mm/dd/yyyy"),index(Σ,,2))))))))